# @media only screen not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive email. In my email template, I have included this tag:

```xml
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and have added these styling attributes for mobile devices:

```xml
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 799px) {

    div[class="column"] {
            width: auto!important;
            float:none!important;
        }
        .reasonDiv {
            float:none!important;
            padding-left: 12px!important;
            padding-top: 35px!important;
        }
        .image {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }
        .message {
            padding-top: 10px!important;
        }
        .productImage {
            width: 64px!important;
            height: inherit!important;
        }
        .siteLogo {
            width: 180px!important;
        }
    }
```

The styling attributes are not working on mobile devices! Please help! Thanks.

Comment: How are you testing?Are you physically going to the site on a mobile device? Using `max-device-width` means it will only effect a physical device. Try just `max-width` so you can debug on your computer.

Comment: I don't know the exact cause of that but note that most of the email clients do not support media queries, also you may want to use max-width and not max-device-width and see if that works

Comment: Yes, I am using Mandrills test email feature.

Comment: I have tried that already and it did not work. It very mind boggling. It works on my emulator but not on my mobile.

Comment: If the image is small enough to not be resized because of the screen size but it needs to be resized as it is squashing everything else on the page, what could I use to make it smaller?

Comment: What about `@media all and ...`?

Comment: Why are you using an attribute selector instead of the standard way div.column? And you should use CSS specifity/priority instead of !important statements.

How about ```@media (max-width…``` ?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found out that most email providers do not support the @media query tag!